# Expectation of dependent Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, markov-process, bernoulli-distribution

Let's say the Bernoulli random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ follow a Markov process of order 1. Does this imply that for $t=1,...,n$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(X_t)=P(X_t=1\mid X_{t-1}=x_{t-1})
\end{equation}
?

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but not quite.

A Bernoulli random variable can only take values $0$ and $1$, leading to the straightforward calculation
$$E(X) = 1\cdot P(X=1) + 0\cdot P(X=0) = P(X=1).$$

If we condition on an event $B$, almost nothing changes:
$$E(X|B) = P(X=1|B).$$

So for a markov chain, it is true that
$$E(X_t|X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{t-1}) = E(X_t|X_{t-1}) = P(X_t=1|X_{t-1} = x_{t-1})$$
However, this is not what you have written and generally speaking $E(X_t)$ is not the same as $E(X_t|X_{t-1})$.

---

Example, suppose $X_1 \sim \text{Bern}(1/2)$ and $X_t \sim \text{Bern}(p_{x_{t-1}})$ for $t \geq 2$, where $p_0 = 0$ and $p_1=1$. Then for any $t$ we have
$$E(X_t) = \frac{1}{2}$$
but we also have
$$E(X_t|X_{t-1}) = P(X_t=1|X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}) = \begin{cases}
0, & x_{t-1}=0 \\[1.2ex]
1, & x_{t-1}=1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The sudden appearance of "$x_{t-1}$" in your assertion is difficult to interpret.  What does it mean?  It looks superfluous as well as being undefined.  What would be the difference, if any, between $P(X_t=1\mid X_{t-1})$ and $P(X_t=1\mid X_{t-1}=x_{t-1})$?

Comment: @whuber, It may be a slight abuse of notation, but (as I'm sure you can intuit) $x_{t-1}$ refers to the realized value of the RV $X_{t-1}$. I am trying to show that $E(X_t|X_{t-1})$ depends *explicitly* on the realized value of $X_{t-1}$. Moreover, I don't see that I have written $P(X_t=1|X_{t-1})$ anywhere in this answer (although I do use this notation in the expected value). If you feel that this answer can be improved by changing the notation, constructive comments/suggestions (or edits) are welcome.